# writing javascript div in html

Tags: jquery

i have put  in my source code to show live twitter search result on my webpage.

Although it shows the search result but when i open the source code of my webpage it don't shows the tweets text in my source code.iT DYNAMICALLY LOADS IT I GUESS.

iS there a way out to fetch the content of div and write it with some functions like document.write or etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a Firefox extension like [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) to view the source code after it has been modified by JavaScript. Install the toolbar, and from the new "View Source" menu select "View Generated Source".

Alternatively, [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) will also let you browse through the modified DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have tools that'll let you see the *rendered* source.

There's the Firebug plugin for Firefox. In Chrome and IE8 it's built in (hit Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 respectively)

Comment: hi David Hedlund, how can i fetch the content and write it in html source, Is it possible?

Comment: @user333060: i'm not sure what you mean by that question...?